# mysql server overloading without error

Tags: mysql

I have a serious problem on my server with MySQL server, it overload itself without any error in

> /var/log/mysqld

What steps should I do to find out the problem ?

my.cnf is

```
[mysqld]
set-variable=local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
old_passwords=1

skip-bdb
set-variable = innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M
set-variable = innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
set-variable = innodb_log_file_size=128M
set-variable = innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:1000M:autoextend
```

Please help, thx

Comment: what do you mean by overload?

Comment: top shows 200% of CPU usage

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start in a situation like this would simply be to open up the mysql program, connect, then run this:

```
$ show processlist;
```

That will give you a list of processes running. From there you should be able to see what process is sucking up all the cpu. You can also run "show full processlist" to see the whole command if it is cut off. Phpmyadmin makes this a little easier by clicking on "processes" on the main page. You can even kill processes by specifying the pid.

If you can't figure out why it is overloading from this information, you should turn on the query log and slow query log and examine what the mysql server is being asked to do:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html